# Azure Web Job Monitoring and Alert

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have 1 web site and 3 Web jobs in one Windows Azure Web site (or Windows Azure Web App after the recent name change). I have all kinds of monitoring and alerts in place for the website but nothing for the Web Jobs at this point.
I am sure that Microsoft has the Web Job monitoring in their backlog but what is the recommended solution in the mean time?

In the last week, suddenly all the 3 web jobs stopped (scheduled to run continuously) around 4 AM early morning - it tries to restart but gets in to "pending restart" mode immediately. I am working with Microsoft support on this. But how do I send an alert once similar situation happens?

Any 3rd party extension already there to monitor the jobs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If third-party services are a consideration, look into CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com - it has tons of Azure-specific goodies for monitoring and automation and special support for monitoring of scheduled or on-demand Webjobs.  It can also request kick-off of on-demand jobs.  CloudMonix is a successor to AzureWatch,  one of the early adaptors in Azure monitoring/auto-scaling space

HTH

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with the company